# Is it possible to completely reset an iPhone so its software/firmware is guaranteed to be 100% factory fresh?

Tags: iphone, security, jailbreak, privacy, restart

When purchasing a used iPhone with a completely unknown history (which includes the possibility of multiple previous owners), is it possible to reset it and be ***sure*** that all software and firmware on it is 100% identical to the factory image?

Please keep in mind that since the history is unknown, it's possible the device was previously jailbroken/unlocked/rooted/etc.

If the answer varies depending on iPhone model, please indicate to which models your answer pertains.

I'm interested in answers for all iPhone models.

---

Please note:
The question and answers at [Is it possible to return the iPhone to its very original factory state?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7691/is-it-possible-to-return-the-iphone-to-its-very-original-factory-state) do not help because they do not take in account the possibility of the phone being jailbroken/unlocked/rooted/etc.  Also, that question is ambiguous as to whether or not it applies to both the software **and** firmware.

Comment: @nohillside Except I specifically stated that the iPhone may have been "jailbroken/unlocked/rooted/etc", which the other question does not include.  This question also requires both software ***and*** firmware to be restored, while the other question is ambiguous, as that entire question consists of under 20 words.  Furthermore, that ambiguous question is just shy of a decade old and is without an accepted answer.

Comment: We close as duplicate when the answers are the same, even if the question is worded differently.

Comment: @nohillside I don't think you're understanding... the question is different in 2 key regards.

Comment: Then please edit the question to make it clear why resetting via iTunes will not solve the problem you have. Right now it only says that the other answers don't help you because you don't have a Mac.

Comment: OTOH no reset method can give you a 100% guarantee that everything will be reset. Malware could have found a way to evade a full reset.

Comment: @nohillside I will edit the question.  If you take a moment and look at the previous edits, what you are claiming I wrote is not what I wrote.  As the record clearly shows, someone else edited the question to say that.  Regarding malware, if you have a CVE reference for a flaw in Apple's device reset security, please do post it.  If you are aware of something Apple does not know, you can report it to their security department privately.  They may even provide a reward.

Comment: @nohillside Editing done.  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but I don't think this changes anything. "Resetting via iTunes" also works for jailbroken phones. Also, I'm not aware of any such malware currently, it's just that there is no way to "be sure that all software and firmware on it is 100% identical to the factory image".

Comment: I've added another duplicate which mentions jailbreaks

Comment: Isn't the iPhone also save the first time activation account internally? So even after factory reset it may later ask you to authenticate using this account (AFAIF this can only be bypassed by Apple if you send them the device invoice with has to include the device serial number).

Comment: @Robert If that does happen (I have no idea), would it be stored on the iPhone itself or on Apple's Inc.'s internal servers (or both)?

Answer (score 3):

No, it’s not possible if the phone has received iOS updates, which it probably has. You may be able to reset it to the factory state of a *new* iPhone, but not to the factory state of *your* iPhone, because Apple works hard to ensure that you can’t downgrade iOS to the factory version.

Comment: Thanks Mike.  Can you elaborate on "you may be able to reset it to the factory state of a *new* iPhone, but not the factory state of *your* iPhone"?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket The iPhone 12 was originally distributed with iOS 14.1. New ones being sold now have iOS 14.3. If you have one that was distributed with iOS 14.1 but has been upgraded to 14.3, you can’t reset it to its original factory state with 14.1, but you can reset it to the factory state of a new iPhone 12 with 14.3.

Comment: Mike, thanks for the details.  I was previously unaware of this.  Because of this lack of knowledge, my question is not really worded correctly.  Resetting the device to a new iPhone 12 with 4.3 (using your example) would be adequate.  Would it be better for me to edit my question for additional clarity, or create a new question that would be very similar, but include wording to allow resetting it to the current Apple iOS version?